# On which open set $f$ admits an inverse?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a function $f(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta).$Then for which of the open subsets $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ given below, $f$ restricted to $U$ admits an inverse?

1. $U=\mathbb{R}^2$
2. $U=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x>0,y>0\}$
3. $U=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2<1\}$
4. $U=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x<-1,y<-1\}$

Here the Jacobian of $f$ is $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and it is not vanishing on option 2 and 4. Can I say option 2 and 4 are correct?

Comment: **Hint** For (2), consider $f(1, 2 \pi)$ and $f(1, 4 \pi)$.

Comment: oh, then $f$ is not one to one

Comment: Yes, exactly. Are you sure this problem is correct as stated? The options for $U$ and the labeling of the variables suggest that this problem might be somehow "backward".

Comment: Geometrically, one can grasp the intuition that $f$ is a diffeomorphism from $]0,+\infty[\times]-\pi,\pi[$ to $\mathbb{R}^2\times(]-\infty,0]\times\{0\})$.

Comment: Ya sure problem is correct. It is just asked in some entrance exam. So option 3 is correct ah?

Comment: Are you sure that the regions $U$ defines the domain for $f(r,\theta)$, or does (3) mean, for example, $r<1$?

Answer (score 1):

For 1st part  counterexample is $f(1,\theta)=f(1,\theta +2\pi)$

For second part take $f(1,\theta)=f(1,\theta +2\pi)$ where $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$

For third part $f(\frac{1}{2},\theta)=f(\frac{1}{2},\theta+2\pi)$

For 4th part as $f(2,\theta)=f(2,\theta +2\pi)$ where $\pi<\theta<\frac{3\pi}{2}$