# The Function $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ defined by $f(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let  $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$  be the function defined by $f(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta).$ Then for which of the open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ given below, $f$ restricted to $U$ admit an inverse?

1. $U=\mathbb{R}^2$
2. $U=\{x,y \in\mathbb{R}^2:x>0,y>0\}$
3. $U=\{x,y \in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2<1\}$
4. $U=\{x,y \in\mathbb{R}^2:x<-1,y<-1\}$

It is clear 1 is not true as $\sin ,\cos$ are periodical function. Similarly 3 is not true. What about 2nd and 4th ? please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586259/on-which-open-set-f-admits-an-inverse#comment3229015_1586259

Comment: Do you want inverse, or continuous inverse.

Answer (score 2):

To admit an inverse $f$ restricted to $U$ must be bijective, in particular one-one.
$1$ and $2$ are not True since $f(1,2) = f(1,2+2\pi)$.
$4$ is not true since $f(-2,-2\pi) = f (-2,-4\pi)$.
$3$ is not True since $f(0,1/2) = f (0,1/4)$.

Comment: its means its incorrect question?

Comment: f(1, 2) = f(1, 1+2$\pi$), how come?

Comment: there should be $f(1,2+2\pi)$

Comment: That's what I am thinking.

Comment: oh. yes ..i am sorry for that mistake,

Comment: no, problem at all. Edit your answer now.

Comment: we can't take r as negative

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be properly formulated.

Comment: but f is from $R^2$ to $R^2$.

Comment: yes problem is not well defined

Answer (score 0):

In options 2 and 4, The determinant of jacobian= $r$ is nonzero everywhere. Thus inverse function theorem guarantees that, for every point $p$ in  $U$, there exists a neighborhood about $p$ over which function is invertible. This does not mean function is invertible over whole domain $U$: in this case $f$ is not even injective since it is periodic : $f(x,y)=f(x,y+2 \pi)$. (And injection is necessary for inverse.)

Comment: I think all options are incorrect???

Comment: @neelkanth of course all options are incorrect. Actually many got confused that using inverse function theorem, options 2  and 4 should be correct. That's why I wrote this.